# Which caffe version opencv uses in dnn module?

Tags: opencv, caffe, nvidia

Opencv has dnn module which they introduced in 3.3 version. Earlier it was in opencv-contrib only. 
I am not able to find out which caffe version and repo , opencv use for dnn module implementation?
caffe has various repos and versions like 
1. BVLC Caffe
2. Nvidia Caffe
3. weiliu89/caffe for SSD

I am facing issued while using Nvidia caffe trained model when importing in opencv 3.4 dnn module.

Comment: maybe tell a bit about the issues, maybe than can be solved without knowing internal opencv caffe usage (if caffe is included in opencv dnn at all).

Comment: I trained SSD model using Nvidia Caffe 0.16 as well as 0.17, But When I am using opencv 3.4 dnn module to import this caffe model, I am getting following error: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (pbBlob.raw_data_type() == 
caffe::FLOAT16) in blobFromProto, file 
/opt/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_importer.cpp, line 251
Exception:  /opt/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_importer.cpp:251: 
error: (-215) pbBlob.raw_data_type() == caffe::FLOAT16 in function 
blobFromProto

Answer (score 0):

@sagar.bot05, OpenCV doesn't depend on Caffe library. It can import models trained in Caffe and run them using own implementation. Networks from the most known Caffe's forks such SSD, Faster-RCNN frameworks and Nvidia's Caffe also supported.